# Import EAR project from NetBeans with source code

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jboss, weblogic, ear

We are going to migrate from "Oracle WebLogic" to "EAP JBoss Redhat", so I need to setup this EAR project from NetBeans into Eclipse (a Redhat version), then will work on the configs needed to use the new server, with as few changes as possible in the code.

But I cannot get the source code from NetBeans. This is what i tried:

- Go to NetBeans
- See that I have no option to directly import the project to EAR so I run clean&build.
- Take the EAR and import it on Eclipse. Then eclipse takes my EAR and WAR/EJB files.

The result of this is an EAR project in Eclipse which does not contains **.java** files, only **.class** files on EJB folder.

I need some guidance.

Comment: You can use Netbeans with EAP

Comment: I do use netbeans with EAP, but i cannto select it as a server on Java EE applications, just on WEB applications

Comment: which version of Apache NetBeans/EAP are you using ?